# Update Chart series's ToolTip using MouseHover

Tags: vb.net, charts, tooltip, mousehover

I am writing an application to plot a line chart. It gets a row from a CSV file and pass it to a method (There are a few hundred rows):

```
Private Function plotChart(ByVal sortedRow As String())

        count = sortedRow(8)    'Represents X value
        Dim spcRawPoint = sortedRow(7)  'Represents Y value            
        Try                
            Me.Chart1.Series("Result").Points.AddXY(count, spcPoint)
            Me.Chart1.Series("Result").ToolTip = "Value: " + spcRawPoint + Environment.NewLine + "Date: " + count.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
        End Try

    End Function
```

When I am hovering the mouse to the series at the chart, I wanted it to display the respective X(Decimal) and Y(DateTime) values. With the above method, once the chart is plotted, when I hover to the series, I see that the displayed X and Y values are the same at all points on the series.

I did some searching in the internet and I saw a suggestion to include a **MouseMove** or **MouseHover** event in my chart. I did this:

```
Private Sub Chart1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ToolTipEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseHover
        If e.HitTestResult.PointIndex >= 0 Then
            If e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
                Dim Xvalue As Decimal = e.X
                Dim Yvalue As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Y)
                Me.Chart1.Series("Result").ToolTip = "Value: " + Xvalue + Environment.NewLine + "Date: " + Yvalue.ToString
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code is able to build, but when I run it an exception occurs:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ToolTipEventArgs'.
```

I see that it is a casting problem but I am out of idea on how to solve it. 
What I need is when I hover my mouse to the mentioned series at the chart area, the tooltip shall show the X and Y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the MouseHover event:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseHover
        Me.Chart1.Series("Result").ToolTip = "#VALY{F}\n#VALX"    
    End Sub
```

Now, I can see the X and Y values whenever I Hover my mouse on the series of the chart.